# Google app engine and prediction API (error import)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-prediction

Please help me to solve this error? I'm doing this exercise on app engine (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/prediction_service_accounts) , but I'm stuck in step 6.2 because I raise this error(When I run the deploy operation, it is successful step 6.1):

: No module named appengine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~01prediction/1.367567721220366691/main.py", line 29, in 
    from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

The error in line 29 :
 from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

Answer (score 0):

Did you run step 3.2? That should have copied some folders into `prediction-demo-skeleton`. You should have a folder called `oauth2client` inside `prediction-demo-skeleton`. Take a look at the folders that are inside `prediction-demo-full`.

ps: a good practice before deploying is to run your app using the devappserver.

Comment: yes, I run a successful transition 3.2 and the folder is present oauth2client.

Answer (score 0):

The Google API Python Client now has a pre-packaged ZIP containing all dependencies that might make installation easier. See:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/list

Select `google-api-python-client-gae-1.1.zip` for download. Unzip this file inside of your AppEngine app directory.

Along the lines of Sebastian's suggestion it generally is a good idea to test locally using the devappserver. In this case you should be able to get past the import issue, however AppAssertionCredentials won't actually be able to generate any access tokens until it is deployed into a production environment, so it will be of limited use for you.